# Is it possible to train conditional GAN with 1 label

Tags: computer-vision, generative-adversarial-network

cGAN is used to generate images of specified class, but i wonder what happen if we use the cGAN, but only train on dataset with only 1 class.

Answer (score 0):

If it has one class, then you don't need any condition. It's self conditioned in that class. You can just train a normal GAN on that class of images.

Comment: Suppose if i already had a cGAN and i use that code to train on 1 class dataset. Is it possible.

Comment: If you want to use the same code, then it is possible. However, the core benefits of conditional GANs will be missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 1 class then you don't need conditional GAN, just do a simple DCGAN to generate images that look like the ones you provide to the model.